# Android project build issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

**Android project build fail**

In android studio (updated ide - dolphin) build failed , please suggest any one, how can we solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tested restarting your computer?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Studio go to: `File` > `Invalidate Caches Restart`

If that doesn't work, try to restart your computer, to kill all the pending process running.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Studio go to: File > Invalidate Caches Restart
and also **open task manager and all background task end then again restart**
after that working successfully.